# FormatException при заполнении DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#

Прошу помочь с `DataGridViev`. Мне нужно, чтобы была таблица в 2 столбца с ранее указанным количеством строк (`gg`). В 1-м столбце должны быть номера по порядку, а во второй значения температур по формулам.

Моя попытка решения внизу. В ней при нажатии кнопки "заполнить таблицу" (button 4) программа вылетает с ошибкой:

> Необработанное исключение типа "System.FormatException" в mscorlib.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Входная строка имела неверный формат.

Код:

```
int gg = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);

double
      z_pnd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text), 
      z_pvd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text),
      t_kond = Convert.ToDouble(textBox8.Text), 
      t_dear = Convert.ToDouble(textBox9.Text),
      t_oe = Convert.ToDouble(textBox10.Text), 
      t_egu = Convert.ToDouble(textBox11.Text),
      z = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text), 
      alfa = 0.9, tp_pereddear = t_dear - 10,
      t_nach = Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text), 
      p_pg = Convert.ToDouble(textBox7.Text),

      t_pv = ((t_nach - t_kond - t_oe - t_egu) / (z + 1)),
      t_pvopt = t_nach - t_pv,
      t_pvek = alfa * (t_pvopt - t_kond) + t_kond,
      delt_pvd = (t_pvek - t_dear) / z_pvd,
      delt_pnd = (tp_pereddear - t_kond - t_oe - t_egu) / z_pnd;

double[] x = new double[gg];
double[] y = new double[gg];

for (int i = 0; i <= gg - 1; i++) 
{ 
    if (i == 0) 
    {
        x[i] = 1; 
        y[i] = (t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + t_pv);
    } 
    else 
    { 
        y[0] = (t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + t_pv); 
        x[i] = (i + 1); 
        y[i] = (y[0] + t_pv*i); 
    } 

    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = x[i].ToString(); 
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = y[i].ToString();
```

Comment: А, что сами вы дебажить не умеете? Поставьте точку останова вначале метода, где происходит конвертация, и пройдите по-шагам, просматривая значения переменных, и вскоре сами найдете, где у вас криво. Навык поиска и исправления ошибок такой же необходимый в профессии как и собственно написание кода.

Comment: @МихаилК Добавьте в вопрос значения, содержащиеся во всех упомянутых в коде `textBoxxxx` - на момент выполнения `button4_Click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в вопрос значения, содержащиеся во всех упомянутых в коде `textBoxxxx`.

Проверяйте все строки, которые должны содержать числа:

*(Ну и нельзя же так поступать с людьми. Что у Вас творится в цикле?)*

```
private bool CheckInput_Int(TextBox aControl)
{
  int value;
  return int.TryParse(aControl.Text, out value);
}
private bool CheckInput_Double(TextBox aControl)
{
  double value;
  bool result = double.TryParse(aControl.Text, out value);
  if (!result)
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Could not convert text [{0}] from control {1} to number.", aControl.Text, aControl.Name),
      "Error!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
  return result;
}

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!CheckInput_Int(textBox2) || 
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox4) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox3) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox8) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox9) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox10) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox11) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox6) ||
      !CheckInput_Double(textBox7)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Проверьте значения полей!", "Внимание!", 
      MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
    return;
  }

  ...

  double yBase = t_kond + t_oe + t_egu + t_pv;
  for (int i = 0; i < gg; i++) 
  { 
    x[i] = i + 1; 
    y[i] = yBase + t_pv * i; 

    ...
  }
```

Comment: @МихаилК - и не должно было заработать. Я всего лишь навел относительный порядок в цикле, но причина ошибки скрывается в значениях контролов `TextBox`, которые не могут быть преобразованы в числа.

Comment: @МихаилК Вы слышали такое выражение: "Глас вопиющего в пустыне"? Добавьте в вопрос значения, содержащиеся во всех упомянутых в коде `textBox`ax - на момент выполнения `button4_Click`.

Comment: @МихаилК хм, хорошо. Какое значение (текст, строка) содержится в `textBox2` в момент нажатия на `button4`?

Comment: @МихаилК Вы мне просто на последний вопрос ответьте, а то у нас получается разговор немого с глухим.

Comment: @МихаилК Хорошо, наметился прогресс :). Теперь перечислите, что содержится в остальных восьми текстбоксах.

Comment: @МихаилК a в 3-м и 4-м что? `textBox12` не используется в `button4_Click`.

Comment: Как зачем? А строчки `z_pnd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox4.Text)` и `z_pvd = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text),` в Вашем коде тогда зачем?

Comment: @МихаилК Обратите внимание, что я не стал копировать весь Ваш код, а пропустил его поставив многоточия.

Comment: Большое спасибо,вот от всей души,без вашей помощи никуда!!!

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что какой-то метод из `Convert` не может преобразовать строку в требуемый тип, так как «строка имеет неверный формат». Обратите внимание на то, какое значение передается из свойства `Text` у `TextBox`.

Если есть необходимость конкретизировать формат строки, то воспользуйтесь методом принимающий экземпляр `IFormatProvider`, например: [Convert.ToDouble(String, IFormatProvider)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9s9ak971(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: По ссылке в моем комментарии есть пример кода. Если вкратце, то вы передаете строку как аргумент для ToDouble(string) которая не может быть преобразована в тип double, так как содержит недопустимые символы для этого типа.